# Dependency Walker for Java?

Tags: java, class, dependencies

I am looking for a tool that lists the .class dependencies for a given Java class to run.  Kind of like what [Dependency Walker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235265.aspx) does for Windows applications.

I am aware of some tools, but they are overly complicated or not quite a match, including

- [Class Dependency Analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/)
- [GenJar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/genjar/)
- [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/)
- [One-JAR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/one-jar/)

Any suggestions?  TIA!!

Comment: You say some don't match, but you don't give reasons that they match or what exactly you are after.

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: I have a class that accepts a cleartext password and returns the ciphertext equivalent.  It is a simple CLI utility and, per the vendor, requires 26MB of custom JAR files to run.

I am tasked with identifying and collating the actual class files dependencies in order to efficiently use space.

Something trusty like Dependency Walker would nail this in no time.
Something like Dependency Finder tried, and then spent 2hr at 100% CPU utilization before I killed the process.

Hope that helps and thanks for the oppty to refine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM will only load classes that are actually referenced in the program. Therefore, you will probably not be able to reduce runtime memory consumption by pruning the dependencies. If you are after reducing program size to ease deployment though, you can use this to detect which classes are actually needed: Simply run the application with the VM's class loading logging enabled, and the logfile will list all used classes.

For instance, for the Sun JVM, you would add the VM parameter `-verbose:class`, i.e. launch your application as follows:

```
java -verbose:class -cp thejarfiles package.Main password
```

and postprocess the log to extract all class names.

(Of course this approach assumes the same classes are used for each execution of the program, which is probably the case for your "simple CLI utility")

Comment: Awesome, thx meriton.  That works great, and also exposed my flaw in my logic.  I was tacitly equating a .class file with a DLL.  Oops: a JAR is like a DLL.  You helped me see that cutting up a JAR is like cutting up a DLL.  Just because a DLL's entry point or a JAR's .class isn't used on a particular "run through" of a calling program doesn't mean it won't be used the next time around.  For instance, if I enable logging on the "simple CLI utility", logging classes will be loaded that weren't loaded before.

Answer (score 1):

Although you already accepted an answer, I'd like to contribute that you might want to take a look at [CodePro AnalytiX](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/javadevtools/codepro/doc/index.html) - an Eclipse plugin allowing for code analysis including dependency analysis.